# How to decode a JSON string according to the type of received argument?

Tags: swift, generics, json-deserialization

I'm having this snippet of code (specially crafted for this question):

```
let data = "[{\"name\": \"Smith\", \"surname\": \"John\"}]".data(using: .utf8)!

class BaseClass: Decodable {
  var name: String?
}

class ExtraClass: BaseClass {
  var surname: String?

  required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
     try super.init(from: decoder)
  }

  init(name: String, surname: String) {
    super.init()
    self.name = name
    self.surname = surname
  }
}

func mainFunction<T: BaseClass>(_ obj: T)  {
  var results = try! JSONDecoder().decode([T].self, from: data)
  results.append(obj)

  print(results)
}

func proxyFunction(_ obj: BaseClass) {
  mainFunction(obj)
}

proxyFunction(ExtraClass(name: "Sullivan", surname: "Jane"))
```

I would expect that the `results` array will contain two `ExtraClass` objects, but instead it contains a `BaseClass` object and a `ExtraClass` one, as you may see [here](https://swiftfiddle.com/n7b3ezudfzf63galu6xbnofo7a). Seems like `T` is inferred from the type received by the caller function (`proxyFunction`), which is kind of expected, and, consequently, `JSONDecoder` is decoding the `json` string as such.

Is there any way to get `JSONDecoder` to decode the right kind of class (without altering `proxyFunction`'s signature) or, more precisely, the kind of class `obj` is?

Comment: The JSON array contains **one** dictionary which becomes one class instance.

Comment: @vadian I understand that, what I want to achieve is to get the dictionary from the array to become an `ExtraClass` instance (or whatever kind of `BaseClass` subclass `mainFunction` receives as the `obj` argument).

Comment: `Codable` is designed for value types (structs). Inheritance is a bit tricky.

Comment: It's not particular to Codable. Generics and inheritance are extremely hard to make work together in predictable ways. The right answer is almost always to get rid of the inheritance.

Comment: I deleted the answer because you specifically said you don't want to change `proxyFunction`. I don't think that's actually possible. I think you need to make `proxyFunction` generic for this to work. I haven't found any clever use of `as!` and `type(of:)` and multiple layers of indirection and wrapping things in Any that Swift doesn't simplify down to "T = BaseClass" (since that's the simplest thing that honors all the requirements).